# Passing State into functions versus calling methods on class instances

Tags: python, oop, refactoring

I've begun work on a somewhat legacy codebase, updating it to Python 3. The designer/engineer who built this decided that instead of going full OOP or full functional, they'd combine them into a set-up where the main business logic is performed on a single object that acts as both data structure and class instance:

```
class StateHolder:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def method_one(self, x, y):
        self.a = a + x
        self.b = b + y


def modify_c(state_holder, new_c):
    state_holder.c += new_c

def main():
    example = StateHolder(1, 2, 3)
    example.method_one(4, 5)
    modify_c(example, 6)
```

The number of functions like `modify_c` far outnumber the methods within the class, so it's not nearly as simple as I've made it look here. To be specific, there is only ever one instance of `StateHolder` at a time, and all of the methods operate on it directly, instead of creating a new copy and passing it back.

My question is: if I were given unlimited time to refactor this, which system for structuring and holding the data should I follow? Should I move all of the functions like `modify_c` into `StateHolder`, or should I move all of the `StateHolder` methods out and pass state around?

Comment: I would say "Yes". But seriously, it's kind of subjective and you might not get an answer that addresses your needs because it would depend on your use cases. Which one is easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the codebase you describe and given such time, you should definitely attempt to the refactor the code using an object-oriented programming (OOP) approach.

**Why?**

**If you are going to use OOP, let's at least do it right!**

Amongst other things, OOP is characterised by objects that have the following:

1. State: A mutable **state**, which will represent the information the object contains.
2. Encapsulation: The idea of **bundling together** similar information into the same item/object.
3. Data hiding: Providing a way **to protect your data** from the outside world. In this way the object's state is concealed and cannot be manipulated ad lib (Not to be confused with "encapsulation").

**Following these definitions:**

### The **function `modify_c` is violating encapsulation and data hiding**. Information pertaining to the object's state is scattered all over the place and information can be modified from the outside world (functions).

- The previous designer's made a bad decision mixing different approaches to work on something that could wholly be contained in the class `StateHolder`.
- The point of defining classes and instantiating them is to create models that represent an element with a certain **current state** (defined using attributes) and common **behaviour** (defined using methods) which can modify the model's state. The responsibility of changing the object's state should rely inside the class itself (i.e. using get/set methods).
- You yourself are mentioning that a single instance of the object exists. Therefore `StateHolder` is a perfect fit to apply a classic  [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern, where a single instance of `StateHolder` will exist during runtime. In this way, the **same state** will be kept and does not have to be passed around when invoking the object.

If you do refactor your code, it is much cleaner, maintainable, reusable and extensible to implement a purist OOP solution. Have `StateHolder` as a class, instantiated as a Singleton object.

### Further reading about OOP:

[SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Five basic principles of object-oriented-programming and design. For your solution, take a special look at SRP (single responsibility principle) and OCP (open close principle). So the answer is **YES** and add those methods to the class!

Comment: Thanks for the depth. I thought I had a good grasp on OOP, but this has thrown me a curveball. I will keep all of this in mind as I go forward.

Comment: No problem. Tried to be as brief and concise as possible on the basics of OOP. That's how OOP and the classic [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://example.com) (GoF) book came to be. Common reusable solutions that apply to a very large similar set of problems. Do keep in mind, this is just one way of refactoring your code. It may make your code less efficient, less performing and the effort to refactor may be too costly. It all comes down to weighing in on the tradeoffs. Ultimately, this isn't exact science, Software Design is subjective :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going in the OO direction. Particularly look for additional objects that exist in the system. It is rare for there to be only one object in a program of any complexity. Start by pulling out the smaller objects.